# SQLite Android not inserting data

Tags: android, database, sqlite

So my `SQLite` `INSERT INTO` function is inserting data in the wrong order even though I have put the `contentValues` in the right order.

This is my class:

```
public class UserInfo extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "usersData";
    private static final String USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String DETAILS = "details";
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "users.db";
    private static final String DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE =
            "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    USERNAME  + " TEXT," + DB_ONE + " TEXT" + " )";

    public ReminderDB(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Database created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DICTIONARY_TABLE_CREATE);
        Log.d("Database operations", "Table created");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DB_TABLE_NAME );
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addReminder(String username, String reminders){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(USERNAME, username);
        contentValues.put(DETAILS, details);
        sqLiteDatabase.insert(DB_TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    }
}
```

`LogCat` error stack:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table userData has no column named username (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO userData(details,username) VALUES (?,?)
```

Comment: Please see this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Comment: I recommend you starting using `greenDAO` and forget about handling `SQL` manually. (I know it's oftopic)

Comment: Your second column name is created by a variable `DB_ONE` in your create table query. I cannot see that variable in your class. What's the value of it?

Comment: The code and error message do not agree. It's not this code that causes the problem. Anyway, the order of params in `ContentValues` does not matter and internally it's a `Map` without any specific iteration order.

Comment: Probably you added this column `username` at later stage. Try unistalling your app and installing again.

Comment: @giannisf no need to use any ORM.. it'll have more time complexity than inserting data manually with SQLiteStatement

Comment: @SanketKachhela Yeah I know, but it makes so easy your life, especially in the long term :)

Answer (score 1):

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table userData has no column
>   named username (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO
>   userData(details,username) VALUES (?,?)

You have a table named `"userData"` in your Local Database. But doesn't have a column called **"username"**.

**Don't**

```
 private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "usersData";
```

**Do**

```
 private static final String DB_TABLE_NAME = "userData";
```

**Uninstall & Run Again** .

Go Through **[Android SQLite Database Tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/)**